# Is it hard to migrate AngularJS applications to Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular, migration

I made a small application in AngularJS and want to migrate it to Angular if possible. What is the best tool I can use to do that? Or if there isn't any tool for that, how should I do that?

Answer (score -1):

it really depends to the "original" app.

Here is the link to the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade).

By design you have 100% breaking changes, you have to re-write almost everything.

I never tried that but we have an application in my company that is still on AngularJS. We estimated that re-writing it from scratch in Angular (v6 for instance) would cost less than porting the original one.